# LiveReload fails to reload iOS, but works on separate computers, all on same WiFi

Tags: ios, squid, livereload, gulp

I'm using [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) through [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)(and MAMP as the webserver) to reload my browsers when developing websites. I use Gulp to start the LiveReload server, and I insert the reference to the LiveReload js file with

```
<script src="http://192.168.1.102:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

Where 192.168.1.102 is my local IP on my current WiFi.

This works perfectly on my local machine, reloads both Safari & Chrome.

I also have an Ubuntu machine on the same network where I've added my local webserver to the hosts file `192.168.1.102 my.project.dev` - This also works perfectly.

But I also want to refresh my browser automatically on my iOS device. I Currently have an iPhone with Safari. Since I can't edit the hosts file on the iPhone I've set up a proxy on my local machine with [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/). After added the proxy to the iPhone network configuration I can access my `my.project.dev` site just fine. But, here's the problem, LiveReload does not get fired on the iPhone. Even though the iPhone have access to the `http://192.168.1.102:35729/livereload.js` when I try to access it directly through the url.

What am I missing here? Why won't the iPhone refresh like the other devices? Might it be the proxy that's doing something fishy?

Answer (score 0):

SquidMan's default settings are restrictive, so you need to open up the port in its configuration. I figured this out and emailed the developer, Tony Gray, who has added [the workaround to the SquidMan FAQ](http://squidman.net/squidman/page9/index.html).

Here is the explanation and instructions:

> LiveReload uses port 35729 to communicate with web clients that are monitoring a page for changes. If you are using SquidMan as a proxy server and it is sitting between your web site and the clients you want to see updates on, you will need to edit the SquidMan template. Locate the following line:
>
> `acl SSL_ports port 443`
>
> and add after it the following:
>
> `acl SSL_ports port 35729`
>
> Save your changes and SquidMan should restart Squid automatically to pick up the configuration change.

You should be fine after that!